# karma-htmlfile-reporter on karma start not giving html output

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am using `karma` `angular-cli` to run testcase using `jasmine` and `javascript`.

In my `karma.config` file I added these lines.

```
reporters: ['progress','html'],


htmlReporter: {
   outputFile: 'test/units.html'
},
```

And I am running this command in command prompt

```
karma start --reporters html
```

But instead of getting testcase result I am getting only these.

[image]

Edited:
Added karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Sep 26 2017 18:46:51 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'test-main.js',
      'js/*.js', 
       'test/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter

    client: {
        clearContext: false
    },
    reporters: ['kjhtml','html'],

    plugins: ['karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-firefox-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-jasmine-html-reporter'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Added package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "karma.conf.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jasmine": "^2.7.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-requirejs": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine": "^2.8.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "~0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.1.8",
    "karma-requirejs": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And I got the result as[image]
Can anyone help how to produce the testcase Results in html?

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using ? (Qunit, Jasmine ??), The htmlReporter is supposed to dump tests results in an html file.

Comment: I am using jasmine framework

Comment: I think the reason, you are not seeing the specs under the karma banner, is karma might not be loading the jasmine.css file, you can load it via the karma.conf.js file before the other test and source files, look for jasmine.css in your karma-core node_modules.

Comment: Yes, the iframe is loading. But inside html i am not able to see specs. in node modules i am having only karma file not karma-core. Even I tried npm install i didn't get any karma-core folder. Can you please try and explore and provide me a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use karma-jasmine-html-reporter, to print the jasmine format reports below the karma banner.

karma-jasmine-html-reporter:
https://github.com/taras42/karma-jasmine-html-reporter

Add the following in your karma.conf.js file

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    client: {
        clearContext: false
    },
    reporters: ['kjhtml'],

    plugins: ['karma-jasmine-html-reporter'] 

  });
};
```

Configuring karma in the above way will produce the following result:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, this is different plugin. I am using karma-html reporter.https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-html-reporter. still i tried above plugin still i am not able to see spec files.

Comment: Karma-html-reporter stores output in disk but the karma-jasmine-html-reporter will display test results in the karma context page. Make sure you have the client.clearContext set to false as shown above, and verify your results by adding singleRun:false in your karma Conf file

Comment: No still i am not getting.I am getting error when giving karma start.       28 09 2017 11:04:50.892:ERROR [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-phantomjs-launcher".
  Did you forget to install it?
  npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
28 09 2017 11:04:50.926:ERROR [plugin]: Error during loading "karma-requirejs" plugin:
  Cannot find module 'requirejs'

Comment: Could you share your karma.Conf.js and package.json?

Comment: I have added those files

Comment: You are missing a 'karma-requirejs' in the plugins array, Also the order of the list of files that you load in the files array matters, src files must be loaded first and then any test files.